# IPhone localization: Is it possible to translate nib files easily without having to copy the nib for each language?

Tags: iphone, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to find a manageable way to translate every visible string in an iPhone application.  The official apple documentation says to use .strings files for programmatic strings, while using the built in "add localized file" option in xcode to localize nib files.

The problem i see with this is that if the UI needs to change after localization happens, then we would need to update the nibs for each language individually which is less than optimal.  Is there a simpler way to perhaps tie strings displayed in nib files to relevant values in a .strings file?  or would i have to programmatically have to set those strings for each ui element (which is slightly better but still annoying)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can do is recursively loop through each view and then set the text on them:

```
static void translateView(NSBundle *bundle, UIView *view)
{
    id idView = view;
    if ([idView respondsToSelector:@selector(text)] && [view respondsToSelector:@selector(setText:)])
        [idView setText:[bundle localizedStringForKey:[idView text] value:nil table:nil]];
    if ([idView respondsToSelector:@selector(title)] && [view respondsToSelector:@selector(setTitle:)])
        [idView setTitle:[bundle localizedStringForKey:[idView title] value:nil table:nil]];
    if ([idView respondsToSelector:@selector(placeholder)] && [view respondsToSelector:@selector(setPlaceholder:)])
        [idView setPlaceholder:[bundle localizedStringForKey:[idView placeholder] value:nil table:nil]];
    if ([idView respondsToSelector:@selector(prompt)] && [view respondsToSelector:@selector(setPrompt:)])
        [idView setPrompt:[bundle localizedStringForKey:[idView prompt] value:nil table:nil]];
    if ([idView respondsToSelector:@selector(titleForState:)] && [view respondsToSelector:@selector(setTitle:forState:)])
        [idView setTitle:[bundle localizedStringForKey:[idView titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] value:nil table:nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if ([idView isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]] || [idView isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]])
        for (UIBarItem *item in [idView items])
            [item setTitle:[bundle localizedStringForKey:[item title] value:nil table:nil]];
    for (UIView *subview in [view subviews])
        translateView(bundle, subview);
}
```

Warning: You may of have to check other sets of selectors to catch everything. This is not a best-practice, but it seems like much less work

Comment: Interesting approach; I'll try it out when our app progresses more.

Comment: I try this and get a stack overflow (ie a infinite loop)

Comment: Sorry, there's a typo in the last line. It should be translateView(bundle, subview); instead of translateView(bundle, view); of course

Comment: @Harkonian: I agree. It's definitely not the correct way to do so, but the correct was cumbersome and somewhat broken at the time (this is probably no longer the case)

Comment: No, it's still the case -- the cumbersome part at least. I've been giving this approach some further thought and I see some advantage to it over Apple's prescribed method. For one, you can have a single set of strings files, rather than a set for each xib. For another, changes to the strings file do not have to be reintegrated into the xib via the ibtool. For that matter, a strings file doesn't have to be generated from the xib in the first place. I'm curious about the performance and memory considerations though. +1 to this answer.

Comment: @Harkonian: I'm not too worried about the points. There should be no difference memory-wise, but the call to walk the subview graph could be somewhat slower on extremely deep graphs.

Answer (score 15):

Apple's built-in command line program ibtool lets you do this. You can dump the strings from a XIB, localize them, then create a new XIB based on the existing XIB but using the localized strings. So you can always have a base set of XIBs and recreate them all whenever the localized strings change. More info here: http://www.bdunagan.com/2009/03/15/ibtool-localization-made-easy/.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to read about the command line tool: ibtool. It should simplify what you're looking to do.

Comment: While it does help with the translation process itself, it still results in having a separate nib file at the end which is what i'm hoping to avoid.  thanks for the pointer though.

Comment: I haven't used it before as we don't localize in-house. I was under the impression that you could use it to 'extract' files to something that you can localize and then re-insert into the nib file. The nib file certainly helps with the GUI though..

Comment: ibtool should be able to reintegrate strings back into main nib files that are changed, in order to spit out new nib files that have both the new strings and the new nib changes.  See "Performing Incremental Localization Updates" in http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/LocalizingNibFiles/LocalizingNibFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH13

Answer (score 1):

You can localize automatically your nibs without duplicating them following this simple guide:

http://programminghacks.net/2011/06/03/ios-nib-localization-in-localizable-strings/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should update every string manually. Let's say you have an array, or an xml file, of strings in different languages, when the user changes the language just get the translated string from the array and then change it to the UI.

Marco

Answer (score 0):

I always set all strings needed in the viewDidLoad() method with only having placeholders in the .xib. This way I can localize any .xib easily with only updating .string files